# Account Kit does not 'pre-fill the user's phone number in the SMS login flow'

Tags: android, facebook, account-kit

**Facebook's Account Kit** does not pre-fill the user's phone number in the SMS login flow.

Pre-requisites ensured:

1. `setReadPhoneStateEnabled` set to `true`
2. runtime permissions granted
3. checked on marshmallow and pre-marshmallow
4. checked on single-sim phones and dual-sim phones
5. checked on different cellular network operators
6. Facebook app installed, logged in, and phone number verified (only one phone number mentioned per FB account)
7. SDK version 4.20
8. Key hashes of the development environment entered in the Facebook app dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this feature is dependant on the whether or not one's cellular provider has set up the phone number in the SIM.

In my country, sadly, the cellular providers do not follow this practice.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add the READ_PHONE_STATE permission to your Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go through [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android#configure) they show how you can setup AccountKit. Once it is set up properly, and on newer phones once the user accepts the runtime permissions the phone number will auto-populate like you are hoping for.

Comment: Done it all. Sms-code pre-filling works. Phone number pre-filling does not

Comment: This is interesting. Is there anything 'special' about your case? Is the phone unusual or the SIM card missing, or something like that? I have not seen this before.

Comment: Yes i guess. Maybe the cellular network carriers in my country just don't follow the standard of filling the phone number in the SIM module. That is most probably the case.